# My find command can't find records if the casings are not right

Tags: excel, command, find, casing, vba

My find command can't find records if the casing are not right This is the command I used:

```
Do Until Cells(i, j) = txttno
    i = i + 1
    If Cells(i, j) = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Record does not exist")
    Exit Sub
    End If

Loop
```

So, when i want to find of ex: "P-100" i have to type "P-100" it won't work when i type "p-100".

Comment: Try this `Do Until InStr(1, Cells(i, j), txttno, vbTextCompare)` or `Do Until LCase(Cells(i, j)) = LCase(txttno)`

Comment: I would go with the 2nd option as the first will not do an exact match and can return partial matches as well.

Comment: Also Using `.Find` instead of a `Do-Loop` will be much faster if you have a huge range. Read more about `.Find` [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 0):

The `Range.find` command saves the settings for each parameter just as the `Find` dialogue box in Excel does.

VBA help recommends

> If you don’t specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

It is possible that the last time you used `Find` in either of Excel or VBA you did a case sensitive search and that this setting has persisted into your VBA call.

Comment: Mark, OP is not using `.Find` to find the cells but doing a direct comparison in a do loop :)

Comment: Well i am new... so how can i set these arguments explicitly each time you use this method.

Comment: @user3024808: Did you see my comments below your question?

Comment: Oh..! sorry for my confusion and thank you very much for the solution @SiddharthRout